# Xcode Runtime Error log: What does the [#:#] mean in AppName[#:#]?

Tags: swift, xcode6

I got the following runtime error:

```
2014-12-10 19:26:39.695 Bliss2[21855:994070] Error: object not found for update (Code: 101, Version: 1.5.0)
```

I assume the **[21855:994070]** has a meaning.

How do I use it to track down the error in the code?

Answer (score 1):

That is not a "runtime error". It is an NSLog message and has been executed and logged in perfectly good order (e.g. by some third-party code you are using?). Of course the code may *then* have thrown an exception / aborted, but if it did (and I don't know whether it did), that has nothing to do with the log message itself, except that you're being told first that there's a problem, apparently as a courtesy.

As for the numbers, they probably have nothing to say that will concern you here. The first number is your process number and won't be stable between invocations; it is rarely of interest. The second number is the thread number and is of interest when there are many log statements for discovering whether this log statement is executed in a background thread (or in the same thread as other log statements).